# PHP Warning: Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, centos, queue, phar

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Hi, I get this error when I run a .php file from my cent terminal. I am trying to create a queueing system like https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque and I managed to get it to work but I always get this error when a run the files. Any suggestion why this happens?

Comment: this may or may not help but I've gotten errors like this when the PHP CLI is using a different php.ini then I expect it to... or perhaps it is trying to load something that in the PHP CLI path.. anyway, what do you get when you run this? `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: PHP Warning: Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini PHP Warning: Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is related to a server module 'Phar' which is loaded multiple times. This could help: http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Comment: I commented ;extension=phar.so and it works fine now. Thanks mate